# using extjs Store from Different JS file

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonstore

this is CreateUI.js

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init(); //tips box


    Ext.define('RouteModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{name: '_id', type: 'number'}, 'Route_Code','Route_Name','Name','AddBy_ID']
    });

    Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, {
    timeout : 840000
    });

    var RouteNameStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'RouteModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-routename.php',
            api: {
                    create: 'insert-routename.php',
                    //read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                    update: 'update-routename.php',
                    //destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
                },

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: '_id'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                id: '_id'

             }
        }
    });
```

})

**routename.js**

```
RouteNameStore.add ({
          Route_Code: txtAddRouteCode,
          Route_Name: txtAddRouteName,
          AddBy_ID: getCookie('User_ID')
        });
```

and this is the index.html page to link this two js file

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="CreateUI.js?"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="routename.js?"></script>
```

fire bug error

```
ReferenceError: RouteNameStore is not defined
RouteNameStore.add ({
```

I m trying to use the JSonStore on different JavaScript file, but failed.
how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define `RouteNameStore` as local varible inside `Ext.onReady` handler function.

Because varible scope is inside function, it is not accessible from other functions.

If you want more informations about variable scopes in JavaScript you can look here: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

For accessing stores in ExtJS, you can add to your store configuration unique `storeId` and then get your store in other object by `Ext.data.StoreManager`

```
// create store
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    ...
    storeId: 'myStore'
    ...
});

// get existing store instance
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore');
```